# Printing Issue: Google Maps w/ Directions

Tags: google-maps, printing

I've embedded Google Maps API (with directions) onto a site I'm updating.  It works perfectly...until I try to print.  If I print to a PDF it's fine, but sending it to a printer generates nothing but 3 blank pages.  Here is my print.css:

```
    #bg, #footer, #header, #enter-info, #driveit, #find, #leftcolumn, #print-button { visibility:hidden; }

#map_area{
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:120px;
    width:8.5in;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;}

#directions{
    position:relative;
    left:25px;
    width:3.75in;}

#map_canvas{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    right:25px;
    width:4in;
    min-height:500px;}
```

I thought this would be simple, but it's driving me crazy!

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This question can be closed, as I've finally got it working.  The solution turned out to be adding "display:inline" to the wrapper div, and "display:block" to the directions and map divs.

Answer (score -1):

The solution turned out to be adding "display:inline" to the wrapper div, and "display:block" to the directions and map divs.

Comment: That's not how you do it... you should add the solution *here* as an answer!

Comment: don't post an answer that's not an answer. Post an actual answer. -1.

Comment: I moved my solution down.  Hopefully, this now meets the requirements for posting.